# How to correctly convert jsx to tsx

Tags: reactjs, typescript, gltf, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

How to correctly convert exited jsx file from `npx gltfjsx` command to **TypeScript** file? Couldn't correct the errors.

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react'
import { useGLTF } from '@react-three/drei'

export default function Crown(state: any, { ...props }) {
    const group = useRef()
    // @ts-ignore
    const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('/crown.glb') //TS2339: Property 'materials' does not exist on type 'GLTF'.
    return (
        <group
            // @ts-ignore
            ref={group} //TS2322: Type 'MutableRefObject<undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Ref<Group> | undefined'.   Type 'MutableRefObject<undefined>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<Group>'.     Types of property 'current' are incompatible.       Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Group | null'.
            {...props}
            dispose={null}
        >
            <mesh..../>
            <mesh..../>
            <mesh..../>
            <mesh..../>
        </group>
    )
}

useGLTF.preload('/crown.glb')
```

Comment: Regarding the first problem you can use this [story](https://drei.pmnd.rs/?path=/story/loaders-gltf--use-gltf-scene-st) as an example, and for the second try `const group = useRef(null)`

Comment: I think you may need to provide a type for `useRef`.. in other words, `useRef<any>()` might work for now, later you can provide correct type there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `gltfjsx` module has a types flag available so you don't have to do it manually.

Whenever I want to convert a .glb to .tsx, I simply do `npx gltfjsx file.glb -t` or `npx gltfjsx file.glb --types`

Sometimes this gives an error for the ref, if you don't need ref you can delete it, if you do my workaround has been defining the ref type:

```
 <group
      ref={group as Ref<THREE.Group>}
      {...props}
      dispose={null}
    >
...
</group>
```